# Dynamic Subtraction formula in excel sheet

Tags: excel, dynamic, excel-formula

I need to write a formula in excel for dynamic subtraction which subtracts a cell(of a specified column) from the cell just above it.

For example, A2    =     A1   -    G1   (G column is fixed)

```
    and  A3    =     A2   -    G2
   
    and  A4    =     A3   -    G3
```

and so on.

Comment: The copy-paste doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel is smart enough to use a dynamic reference and relative reference to the current cell. For example if you put `=A1-G1` in cell `A2` and use the square to drag this cell down, you will automatically get the similar formula in all others in column `A`.

Video example: [Copy cells and keep formulas relative to current cell](http://m.youtube.com/#/watch?v=saIfyPISk40&desktop_uri=/watch?v=saIfyPISk40)